# Replacing NA using paste() in R

Tags: r, na

My data frame has 9 columns and 3198 rows. In one of the columns, 'NA' is repeated every 82 rows. I am trying to replace the missing values with values from other columns in the same data frame. Let me illustrate with a small dataset:

```
df <- data.frame(a = LETTERS[1:6], b = rep(seq(1:3), 2))

df$b[1] <- 'NA'
df$b[4] <- 'NA'

> df
  a  b
1 A NA
2 B  2
3 C  3
4 D NA
5 E  2
6 F  3

for (i in 1: nrow(df)){
        if ('NA' %in% df$b[i]){

                df$b[i] <- paste("box", df$a[i])
        }
}

> df
  a     b
1 A box A
2 B     2
3 C     3
4 D box D
5 E     2
6 F     3
```

The code works in this small dataset. I am doing **exactly** the same thing in my larger dataset but for some reason the missing values are still not getting replaced. Any idea what might be going on? This is probably an odd question given my code works in the sample dataset here and I cannot post the actual dataset for your review. The following might prove helpful:

```
> str(dataset)
'data.frame':        3198 obs. of  8 variables:
$ Local Identifier         : chr  "NEZ0100" "NEZ0100-1" "NEZ0100-2" "NEZ0100-3" ...
$ Local System             : chr  "Freezerworks" "Freezerworks" "Freezerworks" "Freezerworks" ...
$ Parent ID                : chr  "NEZ0100" "NEZ0100" "NEZ0100" "NEZ0100" ...
$ Storage Type             : chr  "Box-9X9" "BoxPos" "BoxPos" "BoxPos" ...
$ Storage Label            : chr  NA "A1" "A2" "A3" ...
$ Capacity                 : int  81 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
$ Movable                  : chr  "Y" "N" "N" "N" ...
$ Storage Unit Order Number: int  0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ...
```

The problem occurs in $ Storage Label. Please let me know if you need any additional info. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

R uses `NA` for missing values. Note that `NA` is a special value, different from the character value `"NA"`. Since your `str(dataset)` shows that the `NA` value there is not in quotes, we know it's R's special `NA` value rather than a string. So for your example, it's really more like

```
df <- data.frame(a = LETTERS[1:6], b = rep(seq(1:3), 2))
df$b[1] <- NA
df$b[4] <- NA
```

You test for `NA` using `is.na()` rather than `=='NA'`. Also, we won't need any loops here to replace the `NA` values, we can just do

```
df$b[is.na(df$b)]<-paste("box", df$a[is.na(df$b)])
df
```

which gives us

```
  a     b
1 A box A
2 B     2
3 C     3
4 D box D
5 E     2
6 F     3
```

Note that using `paste` here will convert that column from numeric to character, but it looks like your actual "Storage Label" column is character anyway so that wont change anything.